# Using summarize_all with colMeans and colVar to create pivoted table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I want to use `summarize_all` on the following data and create my desired output, but I was curious how to do this the `tidy` way using some combination of mutate and summarize I think? Any help appreciated!!

```
dummy <- tibble(
  a = 1:10,
  b = 100:109,
  c = 1000:1009
)
```

## Desired Output

```
tibble(
  Mean = colMeans(dummy[1:3]),
  Variance = colVars(as.matrix(dummy[1:3])),
  CV = Variance/Mean
)
```

```
    Mean Variance      CV
   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1    5.5     9.17 1.67   
2  104.      9.17 0.0877 
3 1004.      9.17 0.00913
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to reshape to 'long' format and then do it once after grouping by 'name'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(dummy, cols = everything()) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(value), Variance = var(value), CV = Variance/Mean) %>%
  select(-name)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    Mean Variance      CV
#   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    5.5     9.17 1.67   
#2  104.      9.17 0.0877 
#3 1004.      9.17 0.00913
```

---

Or either use `summarise_all` or `summarise/across`, but the output would be a single row, then do the reshaping

```
dummy %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), list(Mean = mean,
         Variance = var, CV = ~ mean(.)/var(.)))) %>%
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
   separate(name, into = c('name', 'name2')) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name2, values_from = value)
```